# how to receive ViewBag data to js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

My x.js file :-

```
function showSfgf(Id) {
    $(document).trigger("onPageChange", '/v.mvc/Update?Id=' + Id);
}
```

My controller class :-

```
        public ActionResult Update(int Id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = Id;
        return PartialView("Update");
    }
```

My y.js file :-

```
    $("#renderView").load("/v.mvc/View", function () {
    getDetails(ViewBag.Id, populateData);
});
```

What am I trying to do is ,passing a value from x.js and then trying to receive it in y.js .
So i red ViewBag is one option to do this. but in I am getting ViewBag.Id is undefined . what did i missed here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access razor keyword like ViewBag in your script section of your cshtml file, add this symbol:

> @

Like:

```
 $("#renderView").load("/v.mvc/View", function () {
   getDetails(@ViewBag.Id, populateData);
 });
```

Now if you are passing string on your first parameter on your `getDetails` function, use proper single quote:

```
 $("#renderView").load("/v.mvc/View", function () {
   getDetails('@ViewBag.Id', populateData);
 });
```